Is the behavior of log-likelihood and number of parameters correct in probabilistic PCA?
I am studying the behavior of Probabilistic PCA as described by Tipping and Bishop (1999). I am using the R package "Rdimtools" to help. I am puzzled about the number of parameters in the model and the behavior of the log-likelihood. My expectation is that when a model gets more complicated (i.e., has a larger number of parameters) the log-likelihood should increase. However, the log-likelihood for the probabilistic PCA does not show this behavior. Another concern that I am having is about the values for the AICc, because it has delta AICc values of thousands (which I am not used to see).
My questions are:

Is the log-likelihood supposed to increase with the number of dimensions in a probabilistic PCA?
Are values of delta AICc in the thousands something okay? Or perhaps the computation of the number of parameters is incorrect?

Here is the R code I am using, including a test dataset.
library( Rdimtools )
library( mclust )

## Data from: https://little-book-of-r-for-multivariate-analysis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/multivariateanalysis.html 
wine <- read.table("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine/wine.data", sep=",")

## Function adapted from Rdimtools package.
ProbPCA_new <- function(X, ndim=2){
  N <- nrow(X)
  d <- ncol(X)
  muhat <- colMeans(x = X)
  q <- as.integer(ndim)
  S <- stats::cov(X)
  eigS <- base::eigen(S, TRUE)
  mlsig2 <- (sum(eigS$values[(q+1):d]))/(d-q)
  mlW <- (eigS$vectors[,1:q])%*%(diag(eigS$values[1:q] - mlsig2))
  M <- (t(mlW)%*%mlW)+(diag(ncol(mlW))*mlsig2)
  SOL <- Rdimtools:::aux.bicgstab(M, t(mlW), verbose=FALSE)
  projection <- Rdimtools:::aux.adjprojection(t(SOL$x))
  ## Likelihood function from Tipping and Bishop (1999) (Equation 4)
  C <- mlW %*% t(mlW) + mlsig2 * diag(d)
  lik <- -N/2 * ( d * log(2*pi) + log(det(C)) + 
           sum( diag( solve(C)%*%S ) ) )
  ## Compute number of parameters from Tipping and Bishop (1999) (section 4.3, 1st paragraph)
  params <- (d * q) + 1 - (q*(q-1))/2
  AIC <- (-2*lik) + (2*params)
  AICc <- (-2*lik) + (2*params*(N/(N-params-1)))
  BIC <- (2*lik) - (params*log(N))
  Xc <- sweep(X, 2, muhat, "-")
  scores <- t( t(projection) %*% t(Xc) )
  colnames(scores) <- paste0("PC", 1:q)
  result <- list(scores = scores, projection = projection, 
                 mle.sigma2 = mlsig2, mle.W = mlW, AIC = AIC, 
                 AICc = AICc, BIC = BIC, loglik = lik)
  return(result)
}

## Dimensions of pPCA models:
ndim <- 2:(ncol(wine)-1)
# [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13

## Compute pPCA varying number of dimensions:
ppca <- lapply(ndim, function(x) ProbPCA_new(X = wine, ndim = x))
log_lik <- sapply(ppca, function(x) x$loglik)
aicc <- sapply(ppca, function(x) x$AICc)
params <- rep(0, times = length(aicc))
for( i in 1:length(aicc) ){
  q <- i+1
  dim_d <- ncol(wine)
  params[i] <- (dim_d * q) + 1 - (q*(q-1))/2
}

## Best number of dimensions:
ndim[ aicc == min(aicc) ]
# [1] 7

## Number of parameters per dimension:
rbind(ndim, params)
#        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
# ndim      2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10    11    12    13
# params   28   40   51   61   70   78   85   91   96   100   103   105

## Spread of the AICc values:
aicc - min( aicc )
# [1] 2989.55803 2215.44971 1115.22494  666.13959   80.73025    0.00000   54.76207
# [8]  178.27734  424.49583  694.42428 1205.69961 2261.38375

plot(x = params, y = log_lik, type = "b", 
     xlab = "Number of parameters", ylab = "log Likelihood")
plot(x = params, y = aicc - min(aicc), type = "b", 
     xlab = "Number of parameters", ylab = "delta AICc")
abline( h = 10, col = "grey", lty = 2, lwd = 2)

Plot of the log-likelihood as a function of the number of parameters, showing that there is a decay in log-likelihood as the model becomes more complex:

Plot of the delta AICc as a function of the number of parameters, showing that AICc differences are in the order of thousands of AICc units:

